# SQL Update Query

Tags: sql-server

I am not bad with SQL but I am having a hard time figuring this one out.

I have a table called `test`, with a character column called `key` and two `datetime` columns called `TestTime` and `LastTestTime`.

I am trying to write a query that will update all the rows and set the value of `LastTestTime` to the most recent previous `TestTime` for that same `key`.

Here is an example of how I want this to turn out:

```
key   testTime   lastTestTime
------------------------------
aaa   1/1/2012   null
aaa   1/2/2012   1/1/2012
aaa   1/3/2012   1/2/2012
```

Comment: What are you using mysql,oracel, mssql?

Comment: This is Microsoft SQL Server. I had already tried what "hspain" suggested below, but SQL Server doesn't seem to allow a table alias name in an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of these answered the question.  The questioner wants the most recent test time before each test, not the overall most recent:

```
UPDATE test 
    SET lastTestTime = (SELECT TOP(1) testTime
                        FROM test tt
                        WHERE test.key = tt.key AND tt.TestTime < test.TestTime
                        ORDER BY testTime DESC
                       )
```

Comment: This works. Pretty simple, not sure how I didn't figure that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE t
SET LastTestTime = t2.TestTime
FROM
    Test t JOIN 
    Test t2 
        ON t2.[Key] = t.[Key]
        AND t2.TestTime = (
            SELECT MAX(t3.TestTime)
            FROM Test t3
            WHERE 
                t3.TestTime < t.TestTime
                AND t3.[Key] = t.[Key]
        )
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  It assigns the same NewestTestTime to all the records.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ah, Thanks... the updated answer should fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE test
SET lastTestTime = 
   (SELECT TOP(1) testTime 
    FROM test tt
    WHERE test.key = tt.key
    ORDER BY testTime DESC)
```